# Randomly choose an instance from union in F#

Tags: f#, union

In F#, given

`type MyType = A | B | C | D | E | F | G`

How do I randomly define an instance of MyType?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select a random number, then pattern match that number with different branches returning a different instant?

Comment: I thought F# might have a built-in way of listing these union constructors, like Bounded and Enum in Haskell, but apparently not.

Answer (score 12):

This ought to work:

```
let randInst<'t>() = 
  let cases = Reflection.FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<'t>)
  let index = System.Random().Next(cases.Length)
  let case = cases.[index]
  Reflection.FSharpValue.MakeUnion(case, [||]) :?> 't
```

This code assumes that the union cases are all nullary and that the type you're using is actually a union type, but it would be easy to explicitly check those assumptions and throw meaningful exceptions if desired.